# cannot get tab order working properly

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having an issue getting the tab order working properly. For some reason it is jumping from field 1 to 4, but if I shift+tab it goes back to field 3.
I had to create a function that set the focus to the 1st field because when I opened the form I had to tab 3 times in order to get the focus there.

```
function CSForm_OnLoad()
{
 CSForm.setFoucs("Origination"); 
}
```

I also tried to set the tab order using java script but no luck.

```
function CSForm_OnLoad()
{
 CSForm.setFoucs("Origination");
 document.getElementById("Origination").tabIndex = 1;
 document.getElementById("CompanyNameList").tabIndex = 2;
 document.getElementById("VendorNameList").tabIndex = 3;

}
```

Probably I am doing something wrong but don't know what it is. Below is my tab order.

[image]

Could someone please help me?

edited post. here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxhr0ty7

Thanks

Comment: You don't appear to be using jQuery in your code examples, did you mean to tag it?

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: no jquery on that example but I can use it if is that the solution, I have other functions that use jquery. I do not understand your question. what do you mean with  "did you mean to tag it?"

Comment: i am new on javascript/jquery so I don't know what is jsfiddle. Sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: I would suggest adding your HTML for the inputs.

Comment: @cojimarmiami if you don't know jsfiddle yet, why don't you click on the posted link? Truts us, JSfiddle is not evil.

Comment: I actually clic there but I dont know what to do in that page, sorry @reporter

Comment: @cojimarmiami Put your html source code into the top left panel, your pur javascript code into the bottom left panel and your css declarations into top right panel. Then click on the 'Save' link on top of the whole page and post the created url here.

Comment: I guess this is what you asked for http://jsfiddle.net/sxhr0ty7/ @reporter

Comment: You're supposed to put only the minimum amount of code (HTML, JS, CSS) to illustrate your problem, not full pages with half a ton of CSS and JS. Usually by doing so you'll actually isolate the problem so much you'll be able to resolve it :-)

Comment: I am brand new on this field, that's why I posted everything, I don't know what will\won't be useful for you guys. The reason I posted that here is because I don't have any clue of what could be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your tab is jumping from field1 to field4, because field2 and field3 are disabled. If you enable them, tab order will follow normal order...

Comment: those fields are not disable, they depends on the field above to load their data.

Comment: @cojimarmiami, the selects are disabled, additionally the fields below that are readonly. You will not be able to tab to disabled and readonly fields.